# Why getHandler() returns null?

Tags: android, android-mapview, handler

I have got following problem. I'm drawning route on mapview in separate thread like this:

```
 public void drawRoute(final MapView mapView) { 
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
          try {
           //Do something useful
          } catch (SomeException se) {
           Handler handler = mapView.getHandler();
           handler.post(/*show error in UI thread*/)
          }}
        }).start();
      }
```

But when I get handler it returns null, although in debug mode handler returned and error message is displayed. What can the problem be?

PS May be it's incorrect way to get Handler, but I couldn't find information about it.

Comment: I believe you can't draw anything outside the main thread. Check this out: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I add overlays in UI thread and then call postInvalidate on mapView, there is only computations in separate thread.

Comment: you probably need a `run` somewhere around

Comment: and a `final MapView` as well

Comment: thank you, but it's just pseudo code to describe problem. My code works, actual problem is why getHandler returns null.

Comment: chances are that the mapView has not been attached to the window, before that the your thread is getting finished

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `getHandler` method returns `null` because the view is not attached:

```
public Handler getHandler() {
    if (mAttachInfo != null) {
        return mAttachInfo.mHandler;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`mAttachInfo` is set in `dispatchAttachedToWindow` and nulled in `dispatchDetachedFromWindow`.

Instead of `mapView.getHandler().post()` you can use directly **`mapView.post()`** (which seems to use `getHandler().post()` or `ViewRootImpl.getRunQueue().post()`).

Comment: Thanks! Using post, this becomes really simple and useful.